# Transform Rx Observable of items to Observable of lists by n items

Tags: rx-java

Is that possible to emit elements from an `Observable` in groups by `n`? For instance an Observable of `Integer`'s would emit `List<Integer>`'s by 10 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [great page](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html) with documentation on all operators of RxJava. One of the operators you will find here is called `buffer`, which can (amongst others) group the emitted elements in chunks of `n` elements.

Example:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
          .buffer(2)
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

yields

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
[7,8]
```